# Swagger Key duplicated with different params and return

Tags: java, spring, yaml, swagger, spring-rest

I'm editing my swagger YALM and I'm trying to declare two endpoints with the same path and different params and return. But the editor show the error: **"Key 'get' is duplicated"**

**I can do that using the Spring RequestMapping like:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello" params= param1)
public ReturnType method(@RequestParam("param1") p) { ... }

@RequestMapping(value="/hello" params= param2)
public DifferentReturnType method2(@RequestParam("param2") p) { ... }
```

So to handle the first, request URL: http://etc.com/hello?param1=x and the second http://etc.com/hello?param2=y.

Params section of @RequestMapping docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--

**But I can't do that in the swagger yalm like:**

```
/hello:
    get:
      tags:
        - tag
      summary: list of entity
      operationId: method
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: param1
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/returnType'
            
    get:
      tags:
        - tag
      summary: list of entity2
      operationId: method2
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: param2
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/differentReturnType'
```

There is a way?

Comment: it is considered bad practice to distinguish url mappings based on query parameters. If someone provides both `param1` and `param2` then the first found method will be executed.